# What are the best Electronics books that contain real life circuit examples?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, resistors, instrumentation-amplifier, books

What are some electronics books that contains lots of design problems and solutions (circuits that are involved in our lives) composed of discrete components such as transistors, MOSFETs, resistors, and capacitors (not talking about IC boards)?

Comment: No doubt you will get the standard recommendation of reading *The Art of Electronics* by Horowitz and Hill. However, this might not be the right book for you. I can tell you that I've never read it yet I am an experienced (30 years) circuit designer. You should take other people's recommendation on what is a good book, as an invitation to browse through it, see if you like it. It might be not for you. Also, **discrete** component circuits are *old hat* and not so much used in products these days.

Comment: Other than AoE I recommend `Microelectronic Circuits` by Sedra Smith. It's a very well written book and very suitable for beginners. I suggest you read this book prior to reading AoE.

Comment: another source of practical circuits are (e-)magasines such as this link that offer relatively simple circuits to build skills : http://www.epemag3.com/projects.html

Comment: Read the questions and answers on this site. You will find all topics.

Comment: Read the Wireless World magazine. Or RadioElectronics magazine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shopping question so it'll probably be closed.

I'll still recomment "The Art of Electronics" by Horowitz & Hill. Excellent book, very well written, it makes complicated things seem simple. You should consider buying it, it's an excellent investment.

Comment: There, told you someone would recommend that book.

Comment: Ha! We posted within one second of each other ;) I do own a copy of this book and can confirm it's good.